# WooCommerce License Manager allows API access without keys

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wp-api

I'm using [LMFWC](https://wordpress.org/plugins/license-manager-for-woocommerce/), I have generated API keys for the plugin, but when I do:

`curl -k --location --request GET https://my.host.address/?rest_route=/lmfwc/v2/licenses`

Without providing api keys I receive a response as if I was authenticated.

Is this a bug or a configuration issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin's author confirmed the issue and will upload a hotfix today.